# Bootstrap 3 mobile menu 100% height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Whats the best method for getting 100% height for collapse bootstrap menu (mobile).

.navbar-collapse { max-height: 100% !important; min-height: 100% !important; height: 100%;}

is not really working here

Answer (score 21):

You could try using the [`vh` CSS unit](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units):

```
.navbar-collapse {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Also don't forget to overwrite the max-height rule. Otherwise, this worked perfectly.

Comment: I'm using navbar-fixed-bottom with this and it gets 100% height, but hides the first few li items. Any ideas why?

Comment: Whenever I click the hamburger icon and navbar opens, for a moment I can see the navbar full screen (height wise) but it then suddenly goes back to default height (depending on the number of items in the navbar). I tried to set the height using js but the effect is the same.

Comment: this does not work where you have more menu items/links that can fit on one screen and you need a scroll. Giving `.navbar-collapse` 100vh won't let you see the last few links in your menu.

Answer (score 17):

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    transition: height 0.2s;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapsing {
    height: 0 !important;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
    max-height: none;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

None of the previous answers worked for me. My `.navbar-collapse` has `position: fixed;` but I assume this is also the case for the original question.

The key to solve this was to have the child element of `.navbar-collapse` to have `height: 100vh`.

Note: I'm using Bootstrap 4, so `collapse.in` is now `collapse.show`.

HTML code:

```
<div id="main-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

(S)CSS:

```
.navbar-collapse {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse.show {
    height: 100vh;
}
.navbar-nav {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Only answer that worked for me using Bootstrap 4. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an older question, but none of the answers completely worked for me. The CSS that works is to set full height on the `navbar-nav`:

```
.navbar-nav {
     float: none!important;
     margin-top: 7.5px;
     height: 100vh;
}
```

https://www.bootply.com/EGHMYmOz2e

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick!

```
.navbar-collapse { 
    max-height: 100% !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

...all the parent elements up to html must have height:100% applied to them in order to work...

```
html,
body,
#possibleparentelem {
 height:100%;
}
```

edit: also in some browsers  has to be applied at the top of the document in order for it to work properly

Answer (score 0):

If someone is facing the height jerk where one can see the desired navbar height for a moment and then height goes back to default, those can try to set the height using js.

```
var mywindow = $('body'), navbarCollap = $('.navbar-collapse');

        navbarCollap.on('shown.bs.collapse', function(x) {
            navbarCollap.addClass('make-full');
        });
        navbarCollap.on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(x) {
            navbarCollap.removeClass('make-full');
        });
```

and this is my `make-full` class with an animation on `navbar-collapse`

```
@keyframes full-it{
    from { height: 50vh}
    to { height:100vh}
}

.navbar-collapse.make-full {
    animation-name: full-it;
    animation-duration: 0.1s;
    /*animation-delay: 0.4s;*/
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

*Although I admit this is not a very nice solution but it's better than nothing & I'm open to suggestions. If someone knows a better way, please do share.*

Comment: Since bootstrap's nav toggle doesn't use an elaborate animation sequence but just a jQuery `toggle` call behind the scenes, it can be replaced with a `jQuery.fn.animate` with height of menu being `$(window).height()`

Answer (score -1):

Similar than [@jteks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3327775/jteks) answer, it works for me:

```
.navbar-collapse {
    max-height: none;
}

.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    transition: height 0.2s;
}

.navbar-collapse.collapsing {
    height: 0 !important;
}

.navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The best way to do this is to ensure that its is set in the correct media property in your css file

> in your CSS file add:

```
@media (max-width: 768px){ 
   .navbar-collapse { 
      height:100% !important; 
      background-color:#292929; /*to change the background if you desire*/
   } 
}
```